# psql: How to search for multiple exact phrases in tsvector

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

We're trying to search a field for a set of phrases. To do this we're using Full Text Search, and we've generated the tokens as such:

```
sql = "UPDATE people SET title_tokens = to_tsvector('simple', '#{str}') WHERE id = #{i.id}"
```

How can we find those records that have any of a set of exact phrase matches?

We can use phraseto_tsquery, but that seems to only allow one phrase:

```
Person.where("title_tokens @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'chief executive officer')")
```

or we can use to_tsquery, but that doesn't find exact phrase matches:

```
Person.where("title_tokens @@ to_tsquery('simple', '''chief executive officer'' | ''vp''')")
```

Ideas?

Comment: Can't you create a WHERE clause with the `OR` operator between the set of conditions based on `phraseto_tsquery()` and testing each of the exact phrase match ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the websearch version, with qoutes around the phrase:

```
title_tokens @@ websearch_to_tsquery('simple', '"chief executive officer" or vp');
```

Or you can OR together two phrases:

```
title_tokens @@ (phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'chief executive officer') || phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'vp'));
```

Or for ultimate control, you can just write the tsquery directly:

```
title_tokens @@ 'chief <-> executive <-> officer | vp'::tsquery;
```

Although your last example with to_tsquery also seems to work (in the latest version)

Comment: My to_tsquery is returning non-exact matches, such as "officer and executive chief"

Comment: Oh, right.  The behavior of to_tsquery for this case was fixed in v14.  But they thought this behavior change in a bug-fix release would be more harmful than helpful, so didn't back patch into older branches.  My examples do seem to work in older versions, though.